# All pairs in an array that sum to 10 with average/best O(n) run-time complexity

Tags: javascript, algorithm, hashmap

I am trying to use javascript for coding.

I am using maps and trying to find all the pairs that add to 10. However, the pairs are not getting printed properly. Some pairs are getting printed and some pairs are not.

```
<script>
        function twoSum(nums, target_num) {

            if(nums.length<2){
                return;
            }

            var myMap = new Map();
            var i;
            var target, val; 


            for(val of nums){
                //New change added for the recommendation of a user below
                //This makes the answer a little better
                myMap.set(val,false);
                target = target_num - val;

                if(!myMap.has(target)){ 
                    myMap.set(val,target);            
                }

                else{             
                    console.log("[" + target + "," + val +"]");           
                }                           
            }
        }
    </script>
```

My input is ([2,4,6,7,3,2,1,9,4,1,6,4],10)
My desired output is [4,6], [4,6],[6,4], [6,4],[7,3], [1,9], [9,1], [4,6],[6,4]
So basically, all the numbers are the index i should be considered.
However, the output that I am getting is: [4,6],[7,3],[1,9],[6,4],[9,1],[4,6],[6,4].

I am not sure what exactly I am doing wrong. It would be very helpful if you could tell me where I am going wrong and how I can correct myself. 
Also, my aim is to have the runtime as O(n), do you think that my solution achieves that?

I would really appreciate your help.

Thank You.

Comment: Linear time is impossible, the output can be quadratically large, such as with [1,1,...,1,9,9,...,9]

Comment: From sample input, your code never store 6 and 9 into the map, so you cannot obtain [6,4] and [9,1]

Comment: I dont have much experience with hashmaps so I dont know how to go about storing [6,4] and [9,1]. Also, I dont really understand why I am not able to store them. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Look at the if-else statement in for loop in your original code. When it found a target from the map, it will just print the pair and the current val not store to the map. When first '6' is reached, the code just print [4,6] and then look up next value in the array. However, the map is still containing {2,4} because '6' is not store to the map.
If you are trying to obtain all pair, you should store the current val no matter it has pair or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function twoSum(nums, target_num) {

  if(nums.length<2){
    return;
  }

  var myMap = new Object();
  var target; 

  for (var i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
    if (myMap[nums[i]]){
      myMap[nums[i]].push(i);
    } else {
      myMap[nums[i]] = [i];
    }
  }

  for(var i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
    target = target_num - nums[i];

    if (myMap[target]){
      var indexes = myMap[target].filter(j => j > i);

      if (indexes.length > 0){
        console.log(
          myMap[target].filter(j => j > i)
                       .map(x => [nums[i],target])
        );
      }
    }                           
  }
}

console.log(twoSum([2,4,6,7,3,2,1,9,4,1,6,4],10))
```